# didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken same token each time

Tags: ios, swift, apple-push-notifications

just noticed that every time `didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken` is called I get the same token back. Is this normal when does the token change? Does it remain the same for each app install?

Comment: if you are registered your APNS , you get same DeviceToken

Comment: If you delete and reinstall the app you may get a different device token.

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-apns-device-token-ever-change-once-created

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163620/does-device-token-ever-change-in-apple-push-notifications

Comment: If you reinstall your application then device token changes but all time you run your app device token is same. Device token is the main thing that is use for push notification without it you cant get push notification