# Does the implementation of Apns feedback service done at server side or client side application

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

Currently i am working in ios application with push notification.Push notification works fine.But the issues i have faced,
push notification is send after the application is uninstalled.So that i want to know the implementation of "Feedback service".Is there any tutorial is available for that implementation.Does this implementation is done at server side or client side application.Can you explain it.

Comment: Let me clear to you. If user has uninstalled the app then you can't track the notification. In apple there is no way to detect whether has been deleted by suer or not. You have to use some Analytics services for user interaction with your app. Again you asked for Feedback service, There are many conditions like device is in offline mode & your app will not receive notification. In this case after some time only latest notification will get delivered in your device and other would get discarded by Apple.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.any tutorial for implementing "APNS Feedback Service"

Comment: in short, you can use feedback service at backend, if error code 410 means device token not valid, but it does not mean that you uninstall the app. Might be you restores backup data to a new device or reinstall the operating system, the device token changes. So 410 status can't help you.

Comment: Read this links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-apns-device-token-ever-change-once-created   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28163620/does-device-token-ever-change-in-apple-push-notifications  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630585/does-apns-feedback-service-no-longer-exist-as-per-new-apis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on the server side you should check the feedback service on a daily basis to retrieve information about inactive device tokens. you can then stop delivering notifications to those devices.

see https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/BinaryProviderAPI.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH13-SW12 for more information...